Performance review raise
I just got my performance review today and everything went well they said I was the only person who they had no complaints about just to keep up the great work and that I’m exceeding expectations. I asked for a raise a couple months ago and they said to wait for the performance review and we’d talk about it then. They gave me a 4% raise that I know they give us every year so everyone gets one everyone gets the same raise. The problem is i would like an even bigger increase because like they said I do great so why am I getting the minimum that everyone is getting anyway even if I wasn’t exceeding expectations. Basically my question is would it be rude for me to go back to my boss and try to get a bigger increase and if so how would I go about that without making them mad I am afraid they’d be insulted and never give me one again.

There's a company giving out 4% raises to everybody, even if they aren't performing well? Are you sure they are giving those to everybody?

As has already been pointed out:

Do you really know that everyone got the same 4% raise?
No harm asking

Given these two things, it is up to you to ask well, and quickly make a simple case.
Be aware that there are plenty of landmines here, as a business owner, I've been on the other side of this conversation. There is nothing as off-putting as a know-it-all that is wrong.
So - consider only focusing on your merits. Don't bring up what you think you know about other people's raises. That isn't really part of your conversation.
What to focus on? The specifics of your value-add to the company. Be as specific as possible on new skills, speed enhancehancements, etc. that have provided one or more of these:

Increased Sales
Lowered Costs
Reduced Risks

Getting new products / features out of the door without bugs can increase sales. Getting your work done faster, training others can help lower costs. Reducing risks is something that more specific to your company's business, but is important. Anything that doesn't come back to one of these three, doesn't help the business.
Asking for raise with examples of how you added new value to the company is much more likely to be successful if the person has the discretion to give it when can show why you deserve it.
'Cause Joe Schmoe got the same raise and I'm better - isn't a good enough reason. If one of my people came to me with that reason, I'd laugh at them.

There is nothing "insulting" about asking or negotiating about the compensation, rather, if done properly, it shows that you are thinking forward and have proper communication skills.
Schedule a discussion with your manager, and tell them what values you have added, how your contributions made a positive difference and what are the plans you have for your growth in near future which also helps the company to grow. Then, mention that as per your contribution and your market value, you'd expect the raise to be revised (at X%).
Whether they'll comply or not is a different question, but there's no harm in asking. You need to decide what action you're going to take if they do not agree to your ask. All the best.

See many past questions about how to ask for a raise. The must productive approach is generally "hey, boss, what do you need to see from me to justify a promotion, a raise, or both?" Then do that.
